# Ubuntu Not coming Up

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10, amd-graphics

I changed the driver for graphic in the "**Additional driver**" from **Intel** to **AMD** because I thought It can perform better...After that Ubuntu is not coming up.When I start My laptop,black screen comes up and writes "system is running in low graphics mode.Your screen, graphics card and input settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."
And I don't know what to do.please help thank's friends..

Comment: System specs please....

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10   CPU : Intel core i5 5200 U      Ram:8     64Bit    Graphics:AMD

Answer (score 0):

You can switch it back this way.

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login into console.

Run there two commands

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
sudo reboot
```

If you are using a computer with UEFI this problem could be caused by Secure Boot option. Disable it in BIOS and try again.

Comment: When I want to login I write my username and password but It writes "Login Incorrect"....Why??

Comment: Because you enter a wrong username or password.

Comment: I tryed several times and I know that I enter right....Maybe because of my username..what is my username?? when I go in terminal at the top of terminal writes "Lenovo@steve"  so my username is steve or Lenovo??? and when I want to login It writes "steve login:" and I have to write after the ":"

Comment: Your login is "Lenovo".

Comment: Thank's mine was Lenovo...When I write sudo aticonfig --px-igpu It says that aticonfig not command found....Sorry for taking your time and thank's for your opinion....

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get purge fglrx.*` and reboot.